# Bash: key-value pretty printing

Tags: bash, pretty-print

I have a command output in the form of key value pairs:

```
key1: value 1 key2: value 2 ...
key1: long value 1 key2: value 2 ...
key1: val 1 key2: value 2 ...
```

what I would like is to pretty print this output so that the ":" are aligned:

```
key1: value 1      key2: value 2 ...
key1: long value 1 key2: value 2 ...
key1: val 1        key2: value 2 ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can tolerate wrong placing of keys, the following very simple solution could work:

```
cat input | column -t -s ":"
```

BTW, if extract keys before piping to column the output will look better.

Better results can be achieved with awk, perl or python, however this feasible in bash of course, but the script will be larger (I've started but not yet finished). The idea behind is simple: using two passes - the first pass calculates maximum offsets for each key and stores it in array, the second path based in offsets injects precise number of spaces.